# Overriding ItemsControl.AddChild

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to write a custom ItemsControl with a custom AddChild() behavior, as follows:

```
public class MyItems : ItemsControl
{
    static MyItems()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyItems), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyItems)));
    }

    protected override void AddChild(object value)
    {
        base.AddChild(value);
    }
}
```

And I add some element in XAML as follow

```
<local:MyItems>
    <TextBox>kjasdgcs dj</TextBox>
    <TextBox>kjasdgcs dj</TextBox>
    <TextBox>kjasdgcs dj</TextBox>
</local:MyItems>
```

but the AddChild() method is never called!

Comment: This is not the way an ItemsControl works. ItemsControl is not itself the parent of any child items. Instead, the items are added as children to a container control that is specified by the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property, which by default is a StackPanel.

Comment: You are talking about the visual children. I am talking about the logical children!
As a matter of fact this works fine and I got my item displayed on the view!

Problem is, I want to avoid the cumbersome <MyItems.XXXX> syntax if possible, by directing the items as they are added to the right property!
I thought IAddChild did it but a simple test just show me it doesn't seems to be used.. :~ (and my memory was somehow wrong)

Maybe I can just move the object around in OnInitialized....

Comment: @LloydDupont: IAddChild is pretty much obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iaddchild(v=vs.110).aspx